# Python type hints and redefining method as async

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Say I have this code:

```py
class Foo:
    def say_hello(self) -> str:
        return "hello"

class Bar(Foo):
    async def say_hello(self) -> str:
        return "hello"
```

`Bar` is a derived class of `Foo`, and the method `say_hello` is not async in `Foo`, but async in `Bar`. I would like to give them the same return type, but mypy gives this error:

```
mypy_test.py:6: error: Return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, str]" of "say_hello" incompatible with return type "str" in supertype "Foo"
```

According to [the documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#typing-async-await), `say_hello` in `Bar` should be typed this way. The error message indicates mypy sees `say_hello` as a non-awaited method.
Maybe redefining a non-async method in a base class as an async method in a derived class is not a good practice?

Comment: Note: not setting type hints on `say_hello` in `Bar` doesn't apply the type hints of `say_hello` in `Foo`, so it looks like the methods are seen as attributes of different types, which is kind of true (a function is different than a coroutine).

Comment: The base method being `def` and derived method being `async def` with both having same return type doesn't make much sense, because you can only `await` the latter. So `mypy` rightfully errors here. Either make the base method `async` as well, or have it return `Coroutine[Any, Any, str]`, or even `Awaitable[str]`.

Comment: Using ``-> str`` on a ``async def`` is merely a shorthand; it is *not* the same as ``-> str`` on a regular ``def``. Calling ``Bar.say_hello`` provides an ``Awaitable[str]`` which is something else than a ``str``. Are you aware that ``Bar.say_hello`` cannot be used in place of ``Foo.say_hello``, and of Liskov Substitution Principle? *Why* do you need to make the subclass method ``async`` when the baseclass method is not?

Comment: As I understand the problem, subclassing with async def does not change definition, but how it will be implemented. It is a typical case that you find a class from any external library and want the implementation of some methods in the async mode, and still be correct and working code.

So, mypy shouldn't raise an error in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: The annotations `def ->` and `async def ->` refer to different kinds of functions. In usual cases one cannot use the latter in place of the former, both from a runtime and typing perspective.

---

> #### [PEP 484: Annotating generator functions and coroutines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#annotating-generator-functions-and-coroutines)
>
> Coroutines introduced in PEP 492 are annotated with the same syntax as ordinary functions. **However, the return type annotation corresponds to the type of `await` expression**

For a `def` defined function the `->` annotation describes the type of an expression *calling* the function.<sup>1</sup>

```py
>>> def say_hello() -> str:
...     return "hello"
>>> call_result = say_hello()
>>> isinstance(call_result, str)
True
```

In contrast, for an `async def` defined function the `->` annotation describes the type of an expression *calling **and `await`ing*** the function.<sup>1</sup>

```py
>>> async def say_hello() -> str:
...     return "hello"
>>> call_result = say_hello()
>>> isinstance(call_result, str)
False
>>> isinstance(await call_result, str)
True
```

This is indicated by the MyPy error reporting that the `async def` function actually provides a `Coroutine[Any, Any, str]` instead of a `str`.
Thus, if some code expects a function of type `def -> T` it is an error to use a function of type `async def -> T` instead and vice versa.

As a result, all else being equal subclassing may not change a method from `def` to `async def`. In the example, `Foo.say_hello` and `Bar.say_hello` are not less/more specialised versions of the same thing but instead are different things. Thus, a type checker must reject such a subclassing since violates substitution principle: we could not use `Bar` instances in place of `Foo` instances to `say_hello`.

---

While we cannot use `async def -> T` in place of `def -> T` for the same `T`, we *can* use it in place of `def -> Awaitable[T]`. In this case, both the `async def` of the coroutine function and the `Awaitable` of the regular function mean that the result is awaitable. Since both mean *calling and `await`ing* provides a `T` they are substitutable.

Examples of this are `def`-defined methods that prepare arguments and then call and return an internal `async def`-defined method, or `def`-defined methods that return awaitable helpers such as queues, futures or tasks.

However, this still means that for a subclass to correctly override methods as awaitable the baseclass must already define them as awaitable.